# Django iframe gview from fileSystem/Storage not loading

Tags: html, django, pdf, iframe

Im trying to load with gview a PDF file from the filesystem
The file its storage and when I call "{{documento.adjunto.url}}" it doesnt shows me 404 error, but still the PDF its not show.
Trying using one from web, it works.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:450px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
           <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={{documento.adjunto.url}}&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:450px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>>
    </div>
</div>
```

Viws.py

```
@login_required
def CurriculumDetailView(request, pk):
    documento = Curriculum.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(
        request,
        "INTRANET/curriculum_detail.html",
        context = { 'documento':documento,
        },
    )
```

Model

```
class Curriculum(models.Model):
    rut_candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adjunto = models.FileField(upload_to=UPLOAD_CVS)
    fecha_ingreso_cv = models.DateField(_("Date"), auto_now_add=True)
```

URL.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```